# More info about traffic controller in process management of an OS

Tags: operating-systems

I was going through some texts and shared PPT of my university and I found the term "traffic controller" in the Process management section under the functions of an Operating System.

The PPT says, "OS maintains the track of the processor and the status of the process; the software that does this is called the **traffic controller.**

How can I learn more about this traffic controller? I googled and found nothing fruitful. But yes, there's something called I/O traffic controller, I don't know whether it is the same or different.

Comment: Same wording here: https://eng.libretexts.org/Courses/Delta_College/Operating_System%3A_The_Basics/02%3A_Operating_System_Overview/2.01%3A_Function_of_the_Operating_System  I have never heard this term used in this context before, and it doesn't make a lot of sense to me. The component of the OS which decides which tasks will run on which CPUs when is usually called a "scheduler". Sometimes this is split into several subcomponents (e.g. periodically rebalancing tasks across CPUs).

Comment: I visited this site too. Interesting thing is, many similar sites have the same content as the one that you mentioned. Possibly, my professor has copied from there only. I noticed they have the same content! 

I didn't find any explanation for this "traffic controller" except that one line that says: Keeps tracks of the status of processes. The program which perform this task is known as traffic controller.

I just can't get my head around this thing. It is bugging me now.